# Is inserting related entities together using EF Core more efficient than saving them separately?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is saving related entities in EF Core like explained in the below link  more efficient than saving them separately?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data

It makes two calls to the database if two entities are saved separately.

But does it make one call to database if the related entities are saved together?

Comment: `more efficient than saving them separately?` infinitely so - this isn't about efficiency but *transactions*. A DbContext is a single Unit of Work. All the pending changes are saved in a *single* database transaction when the application decides to commit the changes. If you want to discard them, just dispose the DbContext. The DbContext doesn't have to keep a transaction, much less a *connection* open for its entire lifetime. This reduces blocking and increases performance by orders of magnitude

Comment: If you used the old (pre-2000) way of starting a transaction, reading data, writing and then committing, you'd end up with long lived locks and clients that blocked each other. In the worst case, N clients would result in N(N-1) blocks. The disconnected way of work introduced around 2000 with ADO and later ADO.NET, means blocking can only occur when you actually save data. This resulted in *hundreds* of times better performance and throughput back in the 2000s

Comment: Each query to database consists of 1) Interface to the database driver 2) Transferring data between the app and the database 3) Reading the data in the database 4) Processing the query in the database 4) Sending results to the app driver 5) transferring the results between the database and app 6) Interface from driver to c# app.  There is an overhead in each query where all 6 steps must be performed.  Packing the data as described in the link will increase the data in each step but the overhead is done once which will always make packing more efficient. There is a negative overhead of packing.